# Should I use singleton - Http Connection to the server - Iphone App design

Tags: iphone, web-services, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, singleton

So I've been reading about the pros and cons about using Singleton, and I have a scenario which I'm not sure if I should use one, and I thought consulting you guys.

I'm writing an Iphone app which once in a while have to communicate to the server (HTTP) information about the user logged in.
This web service is getting called from different parts of my application.

What I actually need are 2 type of classes:

1. Responsible for communication with the server - responsible for http setting,the url,header,parameters and etc.

2.classes for each type of web service api - for exmpale UpdateUserInfo Class or SendResults Class. This c

The 2nd class would use the 1st , and all through the app I would need many calles to the 2nd classes.

Should I use Singleton to any of theses ? What is the best way to design it ?

Thanks guys!

**Edit**:

Example for the 1st class(Let's call it DataDownloader) method would be :

```
(NSData *) downloadDataWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)
{
    ASIHTTPRequest *dlRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
    [dlRequest setTimeOutSeconds:20];    

    if(retryNum < 1)
        retryNum = 1;
    [dlRequest setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:retryNum];

       // and more of the same
}
```

ASIHTTPRequest is something we're using as an HTTP wrapper.

Now I wouldn't want to call this sequence of function each time I want to send the server an HTTP request, So the option would be to put that inside a dedicated class and create a new instance, or using a singletion.

What I can do for example is Using something like that :

```
[[UpdateUserInfo sharedInstance] updateInfo:info]
```

Which can be implemented by setting up a NSURLRequest using the param info , and calling

```
[[DataDownloader sharedInstance] downloadDataWithRequest:InfoUrlRequest]
```

Now, assuming the http request are asynchronous , I still can spawn multiple at the same time.

I hope it's clearer now.
What do you think is the best way to design it ?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't see the singleton pattern as being a useful solution to the problem you're trying to solve. It's really designed as a technique to control access to a single/finite resource, which isn't meaningfully the case from what I can tell.

For example, is there any reason why you wouldn't permit a user to carry out two network related activities at the same time?

Incidentally, out of interest have you looked at Cocoa classes such as [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? I'm not sure you'd need a lower level class to manage the server communications as you're envisaging - this class might suffice. (Had to tell without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve.)

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget ASIHTTPRequest. It's a full featured network library

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: I indeed use it. see my edit. but the design question still remains valid.

Answer (score 0):

I usually (and that's personal preference) have one singleton that controls the network management (a singleton and facade pattern in one) as to not having more than the 5 allowed connections. Could be possible for you as well. That would be a singleton for part of your task 1.
But as BobC has already pointed out, ASIHTTPRequest should do everything you need.
Don't reinvent the wheel!

Answer (score 0):

I use the singleton pattern to control access to a web-based API that uses ASIHTTPRequest, and it works very well.  ASI uses NSOperationQueues for asynchronous requests, so you don't need to worry about requests clobbering each other.

Because I don't know the order that requests are returned, I sometimes allow my public API methods to supply userInfo dictionaries so my callbacks have some context when they fire.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Service Locator pattern to obtain each of the services needed in your application. There are a couple different ways to create the service locator. I prefer configuration at initialization over configuration during runtime.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern